# How to get github issue url from issue id?

Tags: reactjs, axios, github-api, query-string

I'm making a github issues app, where after showing a list of issues of a particular repo, I want to click a single issue and navigate to issue details page.

So I'm passing the `{issue.id}` via route parameters. Now for making `axios` GET request for fetching the details I want to get the `url` of this particular issue from the given id?

Can anyone please guide?

Comment: can you put up the urls used or some code or something so we can know what `issue.id` is and what the reply object looks like?

Comment: you can use number instead of id to identify the issue

Answer (score -1):

Please check this URL :

```
https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues

Example:

https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues

https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues{/number}



Hope this helps.
```

Sample response:

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/404",
    "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/404/labels{/name}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/404/comments",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/404/events",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/issues/404",
    "id": 322291044,
    "number": 404,
    "title": "Internationalization",
    "user": {
      "login": "dgruntz",
      "id": 1516800,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/1516800?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/dgruntz",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/dgruntz",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/dgruntz/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/dgruntz/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/dgruntz/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/dgruntz/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/dgruntz/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/dgruntz/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/dgruntz/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/dgruntz/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/dgruntz/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "labels": [

    ],
    "state": "open",
    "locked": false,
    "assignee": null,
    "assignees": [

    ],
    "milestone": null,
    "comments": 0,
    "created_at": "2018-05-11T13:11:00Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-11T13:11:00Z",
    "closed_at": null,
    "author_association": "NONE",
    "body": "I miss internationalization support for this project. Will that ever be added?"
  } ]
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19826140)

Comment: @aikeru: Since the requestor wanted to know where to get the issue URL , I had mentioned it. Will update sample response.